# Find the conditions for an image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

A linear transformation $f_n:R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ is defined by $f_n(x) = B^nx$, where $B = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&\cfrac{5}{2}\end{bmatrix}$ and $n$ is a natural number.

$C$ is a unit circle. Find the necessary and sufficient conditions of $n$, for which $f_n(C) $ (= image of $C$ under $f_n$) stays within a circle with radius $100$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to take the magnitude of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes I am! Could you show how it would be used?

Comment: Well a vector of magnitude $\leq 100$ is one that is within a circle of radius $100$, do you see where this is going?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, it would be incredibly helpful if you could elaborate a bit more!

Comment: Do you know how to compute the nth power of a matrix efficiently?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I am unsure as to how to find the magnitude of the matrix "nth power of B".